# anchor background-images only disappears if it has been put in a div

Tags: html, css

The anchors all have 'span' to replace them with a background-image in the css. The problem i'm having is that they disappear when the anchors are placed in a div.

HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <h1 class="hidden"><span>Menu</span></h1>
    <div>
        <a class="social-media bg-img-facebook" href=""><span>Facebook</span></a>
        <a class="social-media bg-img-instagram" href=""><span>Instagram</span></a>
        <a class="social-media bg-img-twitter" href=""><span>Twitter</span></a>                    
    </div>
    <a class="logo" href="index.html"><span>logo</span></a>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
nav{
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/logo.png');
    width: 14.8rem;
    height: 3.6rem;
}
.logo span{
    display: none;
}
.social-media{
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.social-media span{
    display: none;
}
.facebook-link{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/facebook-icon.png');
}
.instagram-link{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/instagram-icon.png');
}
.twitter-link{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/twitter-icon.png');
}
```

The 3 anchors all show up when they are outside of the div. Just like a.logo shows up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `.social-media{ display:inline-block; }`.

Comment: Oh wow, how could I not think of that... Thank you Jakub.